# Photoshop: is there any shortcut to create guide lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, guides

I am trying to create new horizontal and vertical guides lines in Photoshop using:

1. View > New Guide > Vertical (this is for vertical guide line)
2. View > New Guide > Horizontal (this is for horizontal guide line)

Is there a quicker way to create these?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click and drag from the rulers, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to hide and show. You can also use <kbd>ALT</kbd> to change from vertical to horizontal, or vice versa. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

you know that you're able to make you own shortcut for it right?

Open Photoshop:
Edit>Keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)

Then Keyboard shortcuts and menus window pops up.

then you'll have to find the "view" dropdown folder. (third from the buttom)
then you'll scroll way down and find the line "New Guide..."(fifth from the buttom) and put in the shortcut you want for it.

Answer (score 1):

> You can click and drag on rulers to create Guides.

If you want a horizontal Guide, click and drag from Horizontal Ruler, while for vertical use the Vertical Ruler.

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then press <kbd>E</kbd> and there you go.

Comment: Can you please add one will get with alt+v etc.  Your answer is a little bit short ... Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: @Kurt The "View" menu opens, "New Guide..." is selected and the "New Guide" box is presented.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. It not only adds guides, it allows for the guides to be placed at a specific pixel coordinate and rather than requiring the defining of a custom shortcut, makes use of already existing default shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

THE ABSOLUTE EASIEST WAY

1. From menu "View" and tick "Rulers"
2. Point your mouse inside the horizontal or vertical ruler, Leftclick and hold in and then drag the pointer to the position you want it. You will see the line and voila, its there.
3. Moving the guideline is done by pointing the mouse on top of the guide and when it is seen to be "selected" leftclick and drag to new position.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, simply type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> in Photoshop CS6.

Comment: that's the default shortcut for showing the grid, not creating guide lines